# Zingchart problem with dates not in 24H on export

Tags: zingchart

I have a problem with zingChart and export. 
on the axis-x, i have dates with hours in 24H. it's ok. But when I download csv or excel, I have the dates on 12H.

Here is an example :

here my definition for scaleX.

```
"scaleX":{
            "zooming" : true,
            "values": scaleXValues,
            //values: '1513724400000:1516316400000:3600000',
            "transform": {
                "type": "date",
                "all": "%dd/%mm/%y %H:%i"
            }
            // ,"max-items":        16
        },
```

On graph, it's ok I have 13:00. And in my excel, I have this :

```
06/07/2019 10:00
06/07/2019 11:00
06/07/2019 12:00
06/07/2019 01:00
```

I'd like to have 13:00 at the end line.

Do you have an idea please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and already fixed in the dev stage. The next public release (due end of October) will contain this fix.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I'll wait the end of October !